# How to bind data from SQL server in to Bootstrap Dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing a project in ASP.Net using Bootstrap. I have a table called `M_State`. I need to bind the state names into bootstrap dropdown.

Is it possible to bind values from database into Bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far ? and where have you stuck.

Comment: I have not tried. i am new to bootstrap. I just know how to make drop down in Bootstrap. I dont know how to bind data from database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dropdown is just like any other dropdown with some styles added. You just bind your values that you get from SQL to the dropdown and give the CSS class for the dropdown as "form-control" and make sure you have bootstrap css in your project. And it should work fine